# expand and collapse TR tags on click - folder tree structure

Tags: javascript, jsp, tree, treeview

I have a requirement where I have to display the folder structure tree in JSP. I was able to get the result set to JSP and display them in table. I need help with expand and collapse the tree on click at the nodes. This is similar to the exampe in this website.
http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/

This is a legacy application which uses plain JS. JQuery treetableis not allowed. But the table structure with tr and td given in the example in the site is what I am trying to achieve. My html code is as below.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <ul>
    <li>folder1<li>
    <ul>
      <li>SF1</li>
      <li>SF2</li>
      <ul>
        <li>SF1 SF1</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>folder2<li>
    <ul>
      <li>SFF1</li>
      <li>SFF2</li>
      <li><SFF3</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</table>
```

I want to replace ul li to tr, td and make them expand and collapse.
Reason is UI display would have columns with folder names, count of files, size of file and created by. I can't achieve this with ul, li hence looking for tr, td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use tables:

1. For parent rows, add a unique `id`. For child rows, add an attribute that connects them to their parent row, such as `data-parent`. Children should have both "collapsed" and "expanded" CSS styles/classes.
2. Add click event listeners to parent rows. When the row is clicked, the child rows' styling is modified so that they become visible (or hidden, in case they were visible before). Child rows are fetched by the `data-parent` attribute.

However, I would suggest that you try creating a column layout with `<div>`s instead as they are much more flexible and allow you to create a tree-like DOM structure with explicit children. It might be easier to do with JSP, too.

Anyway, here's a working JS/CSS/HTML sample using a table. (There's no styling for 3rd level item because it becomes kind of tricky)

```js
function toggleRow(event) {
  var rowId = event.currentTarget.id;
  var children = document.querySelectorAll("[data-parent=" + rowId + "]")
  children.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row.classList.contains("expanded")) {
      row.classList.remove("expanded");
    } else {
      row.classList.add("expanded");
    }
  });
}

var rows = document.querySelectorAll(".parent-row")
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  row.addEventListener("click", toggleRow);
});
```

```css
.tree-table .parent-row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tree-table [data-parent] td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tree-table [data-parent] {
  display: none;
}

.tree-table [data-parent].expanded {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<table class="tree-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row-1" class="parent-row"><td>folder1</td></tr>
    <tr data-parent="row-1"><td>SF1</td></tr>
    <tr id="row-1-1" class="parent-row" data-parent="row-1"><td>SF2</td></tr>
    <tr data-parent="row-1-1"><td>SF1 SF1</td></tr>
    <tr id="row-2" class="parent-row"><td>folder2</td></tr>
    <tr data-parent="row-2"><td>SFF1</td></tr>
    <tr data-parent="row-2"><td>SFF2</td></tr>
    <tr data-parent="row-2"><td>SFF3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```